# Add files to track previously untracked

Tags: git

I accidently added / to my gitignore file andd ran git rm -rf -cached and now all my files are being shown as untracked.
How do I revert this?

I have tried git add . but its still not adding files to be tracked.
Also tried git add -A, still all files being shown untracked in VS Code.

Comment: Remove `/` from the gitignore?

Comment: Already done that.
gitigore file is also shown as untracked

Comment: If you have not committed the removal, you could unstage the changes? `git restore --stage .`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I had some uncommited changes , they will be removed too , right?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the rule from .gitignore or use the following command to force it into the staging area.

```
git add -f [file name or path]
```